# Encoding compilation problem with Bibtex Texmaker and LinuxMint

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker

I had absolutely no problem until my last compilation, and I got no idea why I got this error now, because I didn't absolutely touch this line of code nor this page...

Here is the error I get : `Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 8239 = U+202F` and I tells me it's on the line 6 of my main page :

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} %/!\ Au bottom
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % Permet d'utiliser "counterwithout"
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings} % Permet de faire des extraits de code
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\definecolor{javared}{RGB}{42,0,255} % for strings
\definecolor{javagreen}{RGB}{63,127,95} % comments
\definecolor{javapurple}{RGB}{127,0,85} % keywords
\definecolor{javadocblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.35,0.75} % javadoc

\makeglossaries

\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries} % Permet de mettre la police par défaut aux titres de KomaScript

\makeatletter % Pour centrer les remerciements
\newcommand\sectioncentered{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \centering\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
\makeatother

\title{Rapport de stage}
\author{Kenairod}
\date{Année Universitaire 2013 - 2014}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Numérote les subsubsection
\pagestyle{plain} % Pour que les numéros de pages soit en bas

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter} % On enlève le numéro de chapitre aux numéros de figures

\loadglsentries{glossaire.tex}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
% Include la première de couverture
\includepdf[pages=-]{premiere}

% Page blanche numéroté : II
\null

% Avant textes numéroté en chiffres romains à la suite du II précédent
\include{remerciements}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\printglossary

% Contenu du texte numéroté à partir de 1 en chiffres arabes
\mainmatter
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{fancy} % Permet de mettre les en-têtes aux pages commencant un chapitre
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\include{introduction}
\include{presentation}
\include{cahierDesCharges}
\include{rapportTechnique}
\include{manuelUtilisation}
\include{rapportActivite}
\include{conclusion}

% Après textes numéroté en chiffres romains à partir de I
\appendix
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{plain} % On remet par défaut (sans en-têtes) les pages de chapitre
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\include{biblio-sitographie}
\include{tableDesAnnexes}
\include{annexes}

\end{document}
```

But even when I try to copy/paste it in another text editor and back in TeXMaker I still got this unknown character ! Even by retyping it myself, I get the error ! It's unbelievable !
I even took an older version of my project which works fine, and copied its file to replace this one but the old file with my new project, makes the same error, so I believe it come from another page of my project.

If someone got any idea, I'd really appreciate your help :)

Comment: As your code is neither compilable nor minimal, I can only make the suggestion that your file might have been saved in UTF8 format `with BOM` and TeX  doesn't like that. If that is indeed the case, the following should solve the problem: copy the content of your file but the first line (which contains the BOM as an invisible character) into another file that you'll save without BOM and retype the first line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm sorry for the bad quality of my code :-/
Actually I had an older version of my report, so I just rewrote what I did since, and I think it was because I had copied a phrase from the web into the description of a \newglossaryentry.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.